# Archer T6E conflagration

Tags: wireless, tp-link

I am just new in Ubuntu world. I have TP-Link Archer T6E AC1300 installed to my computer. However, I cannot use the WiFi on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS because I don't have the drive for the wireless card. I contacted the company an they told they don't have a driver for Ubuntu. I am facing the same problem with the motherboard and the GPU drivers. They don't have available drivers for Ubuntu.

I have Maximus gene VIII mATX for the motherboard and 1060 1060 GTX 3GB for the GPU.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I as well had this issue, for my setup it was a rather simple fix. If you look under Applications>System Tools. You'll find a program called Additional Drivers, Open it. Browse to the tab "Additional Drivers" and wait for it to load. Amongst the list of other potential drivers, find the one that says "Broadcom Corporation: BCM4360" and select the "Use this driver" option, then the "Apply Changes" button. I'm unaware if a system restart is required, but I always restart after installing new drivers to insure everything is functional before I begin.

If this solution does not work for your machine, I apologize.

~Best of luck!

Comment: for all noobs like me out there, this works only if you got an internet connection and after an sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a very similar issue. I was able to get the wifi card to work by selecting the driver in the options for Ubuntu but now when connecting to a network it never gives me an option to enter a password. I was only able to get connected but temporarily disabling the password on my router. I am still looking for a fix cause I would rather not leave the password off.

However I was able to get it to work by adding the network manually and entering the password before connecting.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/852882)

Comment: @SorenA: Looks like the answer is in the last paragraph.