# Not able to detect TP-LINK Archer T6E

Tags: networking, drivers, 19.04

I recently bought a TP-Link Archer T6E. The `lspci` command doesn't detect it. I found on [this website](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T6E) than the chipset used is  "Broadcom BCM4352" but there is no mention of Broadcom on the doc or on the website of the TP-Link's product.

I tried to install broadcom-wl by following instructions on [this Github page](https://github.com/antoineco/broadcom-wl) but I've no result.

Here is the result of `lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev c4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
05:00.0 USB controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
```

And my `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file :

```
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac

# wireless drivers (conflict with Broadcom hybrid wireless driver 'wl')
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcma
blacklist b43
blacklist brcmsmac
```

`sudo lshw -C network` gives nothing about the device :

```
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: c0
       serial: 90:2b:34:39:b4:1d
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7d00000-f7d3ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: br-0fa1bcff4c11
       serial: 02:42:0d:8a:b2:29
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:7d:e2:c5:01
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: br-5490f8a7b402
       serial: 02:42:9e:dd:1a:9f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.24.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: enp0s20u1
       serial: 96:95:8a:2e:36:0b
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.42 link=yes multicast=yes
```

There's nothing in `dmsg` about this. I already saw other questions about broadcom drivers but in other cases, the driver is detected by lspci.

There's no mention of the support of Ubuntu but I assumed than it should be correct because the Chipset seems to be supported. I was wrong? What can I do?

Comment: Maybe stupid from me. Have you test the card is lock correct in?

Comment: Yes, I checked it many times. Maybe it's just broken.

Comment: Contact bios/Uefi if something relevant for network to configure? Another slot? And I'm scarcely for asking test with another OS (windows/mac)? So you can sure that is an hardware issue.

Comment: I tried to check on the bios but I have no information. Are you sure I should have something anyway if the card is working? Surprisingly, I don't have access to another desktop computer.

Comment: @nobody I changed the PCI slot and it works... I tried with two different slot before. It seems I made a bounty for nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was finally to change the PCI slot. I tried with two slots and it wasn't working. I changed for a third one and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [Broadcom BCM4352 Wireless not working with 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841971/broadcom-bcm4352-wireless-not-working-with-16-10])?

Broadcom is a PITA ([see urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pita)), since they do not provide any information about their hardware. I've had a lot of problems with their hardware (on Linux)
If there is no driver, the system might not recognize it..
The only way to get it running is to install the correct (non-open) drivers.

But someone else had the same question, which was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846888/archer-t6e-conflagration). They seemed to solve it by using the "Additional Drivers" Software, in Ubuntu. For this feature to work, your machine needs to be online (e.g. with a temporary Ethernet connection). Always reboot the machine before using the driver...

Comment: I don't have the same. `sudo lshw -C network` gives nothing for me. I tried to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` but it doesn't works.